# May I access the version of the app at the time the comment was written in App Store?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-play, app-store

I'm using app_store_scraper library in python.

I want to reach the version of the app at the time the comment was written. I can get this data from google play store but in app store comments i get a result NULL. I do not know what function should i use.